# MS Access: Concatenate using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using MS Access, I populated the FirstName and LastName fileds from a combo box. Now, I am trying to concatenate both fields into one field when clicking CreatId button. I used the following script but it did not work.

```
Private Sub CreatId_Click()
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim FamilyId As String
FirstName = First
LastName = Last
FamilyId = FirstName & LastName
End Sub
```

Will be good as well if I can add 2017 after the LastName.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: If your field names are `FirstName`  and `LastName`  then you don't need to declare them as string. Just do this: `Dim FamilyId As String` and `FamilyId = FirstName & " " & LastName`

Comment: The above code did not work. Any idea how to why and how can I improve it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Tehscript, I am just trying to figure out the reason of my problem. Is it a problem having the "FamilyId" field as a primary key?

Comment: Sorry, but *"it did not work"* is rather useless as a problem description. Tell us what exactly happened / how exactly it did not work, then we can help you.

Comment: Names make very poor primary keys. I strongly advise you NOT to do this.

Comment: try `FirstName = First.text ... LastName = Last.text` then concat the way Tehscript showed.

Comment: Thanks for everyone, I removed the code from the button and I added it into the Combo Box code and the "FamilyId" is auto filled with ID info. In case someone may need it or want to improve it the code is as follows:     Private Sub ComFamilyID_AfterUpdate()
    Me.First = Me. ComFamilyID.Column(0)
    Me.Last = Me. ComFamilyID.Column(1)
    FirstName = First
    LastName = Last
    FamilyId = FirstName & LastName & "2017"
    End Sub

Comment: If your are trying to create a ID in a table (is FamilyId bound to a column?), this is poor design. Add an autoincrement primary key instead, save the date of creation as datetime (First- and Lastname are not always unique).

Comment: Thanks BtAccesser, the code I mentioned is just an example. I am not using personal names or family names in my database. Next time I should say this is an example.